# Programmable MP3 player with audio recording capability

Tags: mp3-player

I'm looking for a device that:

1. Is programmable like the iTouch, Android, devices.
2. I'd rather not go Apple, but the iTouch is a nice device.
3. I want a line-in jack or at least the ability to connect a real mic

What I 'really' want is this:

1. I want to set it to record, put it on the table and whenever something interesting is said, be able to hit a marker button.
2. I want to be able to have a menu of movie quotes, "it goes to 11", "what is your name!?", "How you gonna lose your job,... on your day off?!", "Groovy baby!".... as well as the ability to record my own quotes. Then I can just hit a button and boom, it plays the quote.

That must exist, but if not, I can program it myself.

Web browser/wi-fi would be a bonus.

The Archos devices look nice, but it's not clear that they've got line-in's.

Answer (score 2):

Just buy any Android phone and you can easily have all of the features of an iTouch and more. I'm sure you could find one on Ebay now for $100 or less. Maybe an old G1 or something like that. You can use cell phones just fine without activating them, including Android phones. But you will want an Android that has WiFi in it if you won't be activating it. That way you can still use the marketplace and such.

Update:
[I forgot that you could also look at devices supported by Rockbox](http://www.rockbox.org/). You won't likely get anywhere near the functionality of Android or IOS, but might be enough for you depending on the device.